# Ejecutar función si se vacía un textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

¿Hay alguna forma de ejecutar una función en el momento que vacío de contenido un textarea?

Comment: Hola no eres un usuario nuevo, lo cual ya sabes como se pregunta por aquí te invito a mirar nuevamente [ask] y tambien procura agregar un [mcve]

Comment: Crea un evento de las teclas para borrar que verifique si el valor del campo esta vacio. Ya le digo coml seria en codigo

Comment: como puedo poner ejemplos: _¿Qué investigación has hecho?_, en [Google](https://www.google.com/) puedes encontrar información básica, como dice en [ask] _"Busca e investiga"_, tus búsquedas se pueden volver un ejemplo aunque no funcione

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agregale un evento al textarea.

Con *jQuery*:

```js
// Al cambio del contenido del textarea preguntar si esta vacio.
$("#idtextarea").on("change", function(){
  if(!this.value){ 
    alert("esta vacio");
  }
});

// Al teclear.
$("#idtextarea").on("keyup", function(){
  if(!this.value){ 
    alert("esta vacio");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="idtextarea"></textarea>
```